# AVL balancing finding when to balance

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I am trying to create an AVL tree and I am having trouble with my function for finding where the tree is imbalanced. I get a segmentation fault in this function.

```
    void AVL::findInbalance(Node* start) {
  cout << "findInbalance " << start->data << endl;
  int diff;
  if(start->rightChild == nullptr && start->leftChild == nullptr) {
    diff = 0;
  }
  else {
    diff = start->rightChild->getHeight() - start->leftChild->getHeight();
  }
  if(diff > 1 && start->rightChild->rightChild->getHeight() >= start->rightChild->leftChild->getHeight()){
    cout << "left rotation" << endl;
    rotation(start, 0);
  }
  if(diff < -1 && start->leftChild->leftChild->getHeight() >= start->leftChild->rightChild->getHeight()){
    cout << "right rotation" << endl;
    rotation(start, 1);
  }
  if(diff < -1 && start->leftChild->leftChild->getHeight() < start->leftChild->rightChild->getHeight()) {
    cout << "left right rotation" << endl;
    rotation(start->leftChild, 0);
    rotation(start, 1);
  }
  if(diff > 1 && start->rightChild->rightChild->getHeight() < start->rightChild->leftChild->getHeight()) {
    cout << "right left rotation" << endl;
    rotation(start->rightChild, 1);
    rotation(start, 0);
  }
  if(start->parent != nullptr){
    findInbalance(start->parent);
  }
  else {
    cout << "balance complete" << endl;
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: My AVL tree knowledge is a bit rusty, but this code would certainly crash if one (but not both) of `start->leftChild` and `start->rightChild` are `nullptr`.

Comment: Yes that is definitely what is happening but how do I fix that?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. From the incomplete code you give, it is not possible to pinpoint the exact problem with the code. It is possible that the error lays in order portions of your code. Please try running your code through a debugger. You should identify the problematic portion of the code and see if you can solve the error by searching on the Internet. If not, extract the problematic code and make a [mre] (which can be fed directly to a compiler and demonstrate the problem) to demonstrate it. Make sure to tackle one specific issue and post the minimal code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @benharden As I said, my AVL knowledge is a little rusty, so what does it mean for balancing an AVL tree when one side is nullptr? Whatever that is, you have to code that case explicitly. It's likely to be tedious.